# Set multiple bootsrap files with PHPStan

Tags: php, testing, phpstan

I have this structure :

```
apps
 - project_1
   - app
   - vendor
 - project_2
   - app
   - vendor
 - project_3
   - app
   - vendor
phpstan.neon
composer.json
```

I can’t run PHPStan at the root of "apps" to analyze my projects 1, 2 3 etc ... I have class errors not found.

So i made this structure on my **phpstan.neon**

```
parameters:
    level: 1
    paths:
        - apps/project_1/app
        - apps/project_1/config
        - apps/project_1/lambda
        - apps/project_1/tests
    bootstrapFiles:
        - apps/project_1/vendor/autoload.php
```

It's working but i can't add multiple **bootstrapFiles** for my differents projects.

This, it's not working:

```
parameters:
    level: 1
    paths:
        - apps/project_1/app
        - apps/project_1/config
        - apps/project_1/lambda
        - apps/project_1/tests
        - apps/project_2/app
    bootstrapFiles:
        - apps/project_1/vendor/autoload.php
        - apps/project_2/vendor/autoload.php
```

I need something like this:

```
parameters:
    level: 1
    paths:
        - apps/project_1/app
        - apps/project_1/config
        - apps/project_1/lambda
        - apps/project_1/tests
    bootstrapFiles:
        - apps/project_1/vendor/autoload.php
    paths:
        - apps/project_2/app
    bootstrapFiles:     
        - apps/project_2/vendor/autoload.php
```

It's possible to specify bootstrapFiles for specifcs paths please ?

Thank's you :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred approach is to have separate `phpstan.neon` for each projects so that they can be analysed completely separately.

To analyse them all at once create for example a `Makefile` script that lets you run PHPStan separately on all of those at once.

Comment: Thank's it's working :

PROJECTS=project_1 project_2 project_3

analyze:
 $(foreach var,$(PROJECTS),docker exec -it api_php7_1 bash -c "cd apps/"$(var)" && vendor/bin/phpstan";)